# Find the periodicity with the help of Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, periodic-functions

I have a function

$$x(t) = \pi\cos(21\omega_0t)+0.1\cos(39\omega_0t)$$

that I want to solve T from the periodicity identity, $x(t)=x(t+T)$.

What I have tried now is basically just solving $x(t)=x(t+T)$, but this gets really complex. So I tried to do the laplace transform of the function in order to maybe find out a way of solving it more simple, the laplace transform is,

$$X(s) = \pi \frac{s}{s^2+(21\omega_0)^2}+0.1\frac{s}{s^2+(39\omega_0)^2}$$

What struck me here is that I do not really know how to find the periodicity when I am in the frequency plane. I get a feeling it should be a better way of doing it than the latter, but how?

Comment: They are just sums of cosines with periods $T_1 = \frac{2\pi}{21\omega_0}$ and $T_2 = \frac{2\pi}{39\omega_0}$ so it is definitely periodic of period at most $T$ such that $T = nT_1 = mT_2$ for some integers $n$ and $m$. Simplifying a bit, we have $39n = 21m \implies 3 \cdot 13n = 3 \cdot 7m \implies 13n = 7m$ so the optimal integers are $n = 7, m = 13$. So $T = \frac{2\pi}{3\omega_0}$.

Comment: Ohh, talking about making it more simple. Thank you!